# How to specify a list of related entities with EF Core using only foreign key in a one to many or many to many case

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two entities, `Tenant` and `PartnerClient`. There is a many-to-many relationship between them configured with EF Core like this:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PartnerClient> builder)
{
    builder.HasMany<Tenant>()
        .WithMany()
        .UsingEntity<PartnerClientTenant>(
            right =>  right.HasOne<Tenant>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.TenantId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction), 
            left => left.HasOne<PartnerClient>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.PartnerClientId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction), 
            joinTable =>
            {
                joinTable.Property(e => e.ConnectedOn).HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");
                joinTable.ToTable("PartnerClientTenants");
            });
}
```

Is there any way that I can have my list of "tenants" relation on the `PartnerClient` class as a list of "keys" instead of the entire class?

I.e. I'd like something like this:

```
public class PartnerClient
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public List<int> Tenants { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do it like this to just use my "Entity" in the HTTP API without having to forward anything but the `tenantId` when adding / removing / updating tenants to the partner client.

I know I can just create a DTO an map it, but I would prefer not to (if possible).

Comment: What about having the List of PartnerClientTenant on your PartnerClient? Would that satisfy your use case? I don't think having the List of Ids directly in the entity is possible

Comment: The problem with what you're wanting is that EF has no way of knowing if the set of values in `List<int> Tenants` is complete/exhaustive or not. It would make updates a pain.

Comment: _"I know I can just create a DTO an map it, but I would prefer not to"_ - is the a particular reason?

Comment: @GuruStron - if I can configure EF to use a list of Ids thats lees work and less code to maintain. No special reason other than that.

Comment: @JineappleAra - I can have a list of PartnerClientTenants, seems less elegant in the API terms....

Comment: @EsbenBach EF works with entites, not ids. Even if this is possible to some extent it will require more code to configure.